# Auto Move Yesterday's Data from Google Form Response Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have Google form which is linked to Form Response Sheet. I want to Move data from "Discrepancy Report - Outlet" to "Vaishali Nagar - DTR" Sheet on each day. The date is to be used from "Discrepancy Report - Outlet" sheet from Colum J.

The condition is that if I run the script today it should move data of Previous Day. For Ex. If I run script Today i.e. 31/10/2020 then It should only pick data of 30/10/2020. This process goes on each day. For running this script I will use Time Trigger.

I am using script which is mentioned below the Question. The problem I am facing it runs on the basis of today's date.

Link of Spreadsheet is:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MhCdwFscPqskeeM2Hza-t2VXoVkI6sq3XRCNybMm4NM/edit?usp=sharing

```
function copyrange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Discrepancy Report - Outlet'); //source sheet
  var testrange = sheet.getRange('J:J');
  var testvalue = (testrange.setNumberFormat("@").getValues());
  Logger.log(testvalue);
  var ds = ss.getSheetByName('Vaishali Nagar - DTR'); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  var j =[];
  var today = new Date();
  var yesterday = new Date(today); yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate()-1);
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-0', 'dd/MM/yyyy')

  //Condition to check in J:J, if true, copy the same row to data array 
  for (i=0;i<testvalue.length;i++) {
    if (testvalue[i] == today) {
    data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,9).getValues());
  //Copy matched ROW numbers to B
    j.push(i);
}  
}
  //Copy data array to destination sheet
  
  var start_row=ds.getRange('B7:B').getValues().filter(String).length +6; //calculate max row

  ds.getRange(start_row+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: Could you please confirm whether any of the answers below solved your question or provide feedback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

- The main issue is that your current code compares the dates with the date of today instead of yesterday.
- However, your code can be further optimized. Instead of using a for loop to check if an element matches the date of today, you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the data only for yesterday and then remove the lst column because you don't need it to be in the destination sheet:

  ```
  yest_data = data.filter(r=>r[9]==yesterday).map(v=>v.slice(0,-1));
  ```
- It is a good practice to check if the data has a length higher than 0, otherwise the script will drop an error when setting the values.

---

### Solution:

```
function copyrange() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Discrepancy Report - Outlet'); //source sheet
  const ds = ss.getSheetByName('Vaishali Nagar - DTR'); //destination sheet
  const data = sheet.getRange('A2:J'+ sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();
  var yesterday = new Date();
  yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate()-1);
  var yesterday = Utilities.formatDate(yesterday, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'dd/MM/yyyy');
  yest_data = data.filter(r=>r[9]==yesterday).map(v=>v.slice(0,-1));
  const start_row=ds.getRange('B7:B').getValues().filter(String).length +6; //calculate max row
  if (yest_data.length>0){
   ds.getRange(start_row+1,1,yest_data.length,yest_data[0].length).setValues(yest_data);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When checking date equality, you should use the date value or epoch time. Try this instead, which allows you to pass a specific date as your `today` value.

```
function test() {
  var now = new Date('October 28, 2020');
  var today = new Date(now.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0));
  copyYesterday(today);
}

/**
 * Copy yesterday's responses from Sheet1 to Sheet2.
 * @param {Date} [today] - Optionally include a value to use as "today".
 */
function copyYesterday(today) {
  if (today == null) { today = new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)); }
  var yesterday = (new Date(today)).setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  var responses = [];
  for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < sourceData.length; rowIndex++) {
    var row = sourceData[rowIndex];
    var responseDate = row[0];
    if (responseDate.valueOf() == yesterday) {
      responses.push(row);
    }
  }
  
  if (responses.length > 0) {
    var destination = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
    destination.getRange(destination.getLastRow()+1, 1, responses.length, responses[0].length).setValues(responses);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function copyrange() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Discrepancy Report - Outlet'); //source sheet
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,10,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA= rg.setNumberFormat("@").getValues();
  var ds = ss.getSheetByName('Vaishali Nagar - DTR'); //destination sheet
  var data=[];
  var j=[];
  var today = new Date().valueOf();
  var yesterday = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()-1).valueOf();
  for (var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    var dt=new Date(vA[i][0]);
    var dtv=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate()).valueOf();
    if (dtv==today) {
      data.push(sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,9).getValues());
    }  
  }
  ds.getRange(getColumnHeight(ds,2,ss)+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}

function getColumnHeight(col,sh,ss){
  var ss=ss||SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sh||ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col=col||sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  const rcA=sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues().reverse()
  let s=0;
  for(let i=0;i<rcA.length;i++) {
    if(rcA[i][0].toString().length==0) {
      s++;
    }else{
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length-s;
}
```